# Python Syntax for Update SQL query

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I want to update a table with the following query. I am getting multiple errors on the following. What is the correct syntax for writing the query below

```
 cursor.execute("""UPDATE `%s` SET `content`=%s WHERE link=%s""", (feed,cnews,news_url))
```

The error I get when running the above is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "digger_1.py", line 34, in <module>
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE `%s` SET `content`=%s WHERE link=%s""", (feed,cnews,news_url))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'newstracker.'NDTV'' doesn't exist")
```

The error I picked was the table newstracker.NDTV doesn't exist, which is not right as it does exist, and I believe the error is something else which is wrong with the syntax.

Comment: What does `feed` contain?

Comment: Yes, but what is it's value, *exactly*? What does `print repr(feed)` show?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify metadata such as database, table, or field names using a parametrized query. You must substitute them using normal string formatting and then use the result string as your parametrized query.

```
...("""UPDATE `%s` SET `content`=%%s WHERE link=%%s""" % (feed,), ...)
```

Comment: Anywhere that parametrized queries are explained, including thousands of similar SO questions.

Comment: Changed the query to cursor.execute("""UPDATE `%s` SET `content`=%%s WHERE `link`=%%s""" %(feed,),cnews,news_url) The error is ---> TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Erm, you still need the values to replace to be in a single sequence.

Comment: Can you help me with how that syntax would be

Comment: Exactly how you had it before, except with a different string and different elements in the sequence.

Comment: When I put it as  %(feed,cnews,news_url) I get ---> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Why would you put those there?